# Parse friend request handling

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am doing a query in parse to check friend request. The query returns objects and I could log them. Now when I convert it to PFUSER, and `NSLog`, it gets crashed with error: `'Key "FirstName" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'` Please help me out here.

```
PFQuery * friendQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendship"];

[friendQuery whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[friendQuery whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Pending"];
[friendQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        //NSLog error
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"friendRequestCount = %d", objects.count);

        PFObject *object=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", object);

        self.friendRequestArray= objects;
        NSLog(@"%@",object[@"toUser"]);

        PFUser *user1= object[@"toUser"];
        NSString *friendName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",user1[@"FirstName"], user1[@"LastName"] ];
        NSLog(@"name= %@",friendName);

    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 1 or 2, I have comment the below code, not test.

```
PFQuery * friendQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendship"];

[friendQuery whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[friendQuery whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Pending"];
//1
[friendQuery includeKey:@"toUser"];
[friendQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
if (error)
{
    //NSLog error
}
else {
    NSLog(@"friendRequestCount = %d", objects.count);

    PFObject *object=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", object);

    self.friendRequestArray= objects;
    NSLog(@"%@",object[@"toUser"]);

    PFUser *user1= object[@"toUser"];

    //2 Change PFUser to PFObject
    PFObject *user1 = object[@"toUser"];
    [user1 fetchIfNeeded];

    NSString *friendName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",user1[@"FirstName"], user1[@"LastName"] ];
    NSLog(@"name= %@",friendName);

}
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much HoanNguyen, that worked. I used 1.

Comment: Friend, if you can please help me with understanding, What did that [friendQuery includeKey:@"toUser"]; do. I don't really understand.

Comment: @AbinGeorge If you don't use it, the friendship object from the query only has a toUser stub with a pointer to the user object. If you use includeKey, the full user object is returned with the friendship object

Comment: Thank You Handsomeguy and HoanNguyen, now I get it